# Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. Parameter does not seem to be null at all

Tags: powershell, null

Checking if a file exists on a remote machine:

```
 #Check if Dir exists on the machine we are copying from
            $dir = ($APPROD001Root + $instance + "\" + $type + "\" + $year + "\" + $monthFormatted)
            Write-Host $dir
            if(Test-Path -Path $dir){
                Write-Host ($dir + " exists!") 
                $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir

                #Check if the Dir has files in it
                if($files.Length -gt 0){
                    #Check if the folder exists on the machine we are copying towards, if not create it!
                    $dirReceivingMachine = ($DBStag01Root + $instance + "\" + $type + "\" + $year + "\" + $monthFormatted)
                    Write-Host $dirReceivingMachine
                    if($dirReceivingMachine -eq $null){
                        Write-Host "the path is null..."
                    }
                    $folderExists = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Test-Path -Path $dirReceivingMachine } -Session $session 
                    if(!$folderExists){
                        Write-Host ("folder " + $dirReceivingMachine + " does not yet exist we want to create it!")
                        #Invoke-Command - ScriptBlock { New-Item -Path $dirReceivingMachine -ItemType Directory } -Session $session
                    }
```

The invoke-command that sets the $folderExists always throws

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

the output I get in terminal is

> D:MyData\2018\09
> D:\MyData\2018\09 exists!
> D:\MyData\2018\09 Cannot bind argument to
> parameter 'Path' because it is null.
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException

As you can see the Write-Host "The path is null.." never fires, so the variable I am passing into Test-Path is not null yet PS says it is when invoking the command...

No idea why it does this

Comment: The part that fails is `Invoke-Command`. Variables outside the script block to be remoted do not exist within it. Use `$using:dirReceivingMachine` to forward it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes thank you, did not release I needed to import the vars in the scriptBlock ;)